# Practicing Loose'ly Coupling code in php

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP or any progamming language and im practic'n how to code a loose coupling

```
<?php

    interface IPolygon{
        public function getArea();
    }

    class Polygon{

        private $ipolygon;

        public function __construct(IPolygon $ipolygon){
            $this->ipolygon = $ipolygon;
        }

        public function calArea(){
            return this->ipolygon->getArea();
        }
    }

    class Circle implements IPolygon{

        private $radius;
        private $pi = 3.14;

        public function __construct($radius){
            $this->radius = $radius;
        }

        public function getArea(){
            return $pi*$radius*$radius;
        }
    }

    class Triangle implements IPolygon{

        private $base;
        private $height;

        public function __construct($base , $height){
            $this->base = $base;
            $this->height = $height;
        }

        public function getArea(){
            return $base*$height/2;
        }
    }


    $c = new Circle(14);
    $p = new Polygon($c);

    echo "<hr />";
    $p->calArea();
?>
```

---

Error

```
Notice: Undefined variable: ipolygon in C:\xampp\htdocs\OOP\Polygon.php on line 16
```

Notice: Undefined variable: pi in C:\xampp\htdocs\OOP\Polygon.php on line 30

Notice: Undefined variable: radius in C:\xampp\htdocs\OOP\Polygon.php on line 30

Notice: Undefined variable: radius in C:\xampp\htdocs\OOP\Polygon.php on line 30

can someone explain me how is it done?

Comment: Your constructor in `Polygon` is ok however your `calArea` uses `$ipolygon` instead of `$this->ipolygon`

Comment: i already change but i got new error 
Notice: Undefined variable: pi in C:\xampp\htdocs\OOP\Polygon.php on line 30
Notice: Undefined variable: radius in C:\xampp\htdocs\OOP\Polygon.php on line 30
Notice: Undefined variable: radius in C:\xampp\htdocs\OOP\Polygon.php on line 30

Comment: As a general rule **all class properties are referenced using `$this->`** (worth reading a couple of tutorials before jumping right in a new programming language)

Comment: @apokryfos thanks for the tips bruh, i manage to get the write answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general rule all class properties are referenced using `$this->`

That means:

```
<?php

    interface IPolygon{
        public function getArea();
    }

    class Polygon{

        private $ipolygon;

        public function __construct(IPolygon $ipolygon){
            $this->ipolygon = $ipolygon;
        }

        public function calArea(){
            return $this->ipolygon->getArea();
        }
    }

    class Circle implements IPolygon{

        private $radius;
        private $pi = 3.14;

        public function __construct($radius){
            $this->radius = $radius;
        }

        public function getArea(){
            return $this->pi*$this->radius*$this->radius;
        }
    }

    class Triangle implements IPolygon{

        private $base;
        private $height;

        public function __construct($base , $height){
            $this->base = $base;
            $this->height = $height;
        }

        public function getArea(){
            return $this->base*$this->height/2;
        }
    }


    $c = new Circle(14);
    $p = new Polygon($c);

    echo "<hr />";
    $p->calArea();
```

It works: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e7f79bb186ffac952ebc4c2b5a8098e1efaeb874